Why does glibc 2.40 give a make check error on #27~22.04.1-Ubuntu?
make check shows error:
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/xray/Documents/sw/glibc-2.40/iconv'
Generating locale C.UTF-8: this might take a while...
/home/xray/Documents/sw/glibc-2.40_build/locale/localedef: error while loading shared libraries: libX11.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Charmap: "UTF-8" Inputfile: "C" Outputdir: "C.UTF-8" failed
/bin/sh: 4: cannot create /home/xray/Documents/sw/glibc-2.40_build/localedata/C.UTF-8/LC_CTYPE.test-result: Directory nonexistent

ldd /home/xray/Documents/sw/glibc-2.40_build/locale/localedef shows the following output:
/home/xray/Documents/sw/glibc-2.40_build/locale/localedef: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_ABI_DT_RELR' not found (required by /home/xray/Documents/sw/glibc-2.40_build/locale/localed
ef)
/home/xray/Documents/sw/glibc-2.40_build/locale/localedef: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.38' not found (required by /home/xray/Documents/sw/glibc-2.40_build/locale/localedef)
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffedd19f000)
        /usr/local/lib/AppProtection/libAppProtection.so (0x0000733af8800000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x0000733af8400000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000733af8ba3000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x0000733af8b9e000)
        /home/xray/Documents/sw/common/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000733af8c0b000)
        libX11.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x0000733af8a5e000)
        libxcb.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x0000733af8a32000)
        libXi.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0x0000733af87ec000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x0000733af8000000)
        libXau.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x0000733af8a2c000)
        libXdmcp.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x0000733af87e4000)
        libXext.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x0000733af87cf000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x0000733af86e8000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x0000733af86c8000)
        libbsd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x0000733af86b0000)
        libmd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmd.so.0 (0x0000733af86a3000)

Upon setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH to recent compiled glibc leads to a core dump
xray@instance-1:~/Documents/sw/glibc-2.40_build$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.
xray@instance-1:~/Documents/sw/glibc-2.40_build$ ldd /home/xray/Documents/sw/glibc-2.40_build/locale/localedef
Segmentation fault (core dumped)



ldd /home/xray/Documents/sw/glibc-2.40_build/locale/localedef shows the following output:

There is no way a sane build of localedef depends on libX11.so.6. You made some insane changes to the build process (but didn't tell us about it).

Upon setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH to recent compiled glibc leads to a core dump

That is expected and explained here. Don't ever set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to a directory which contains libc.so.6 -- it can only end in tears.

Nothing insanse. Steps are configure --prefix=blah , make with no errors and make check which messes it up

@NewStudent The fact that ldd shows localedef depending on libX11 means that something about your environment is not sane. Maybe you have set LD_PRELOAD? Maybe you changed /etc/ld.so.preload? Maybe it's something else. Whatever it is, you should find it and undo that before you have any hope of make check working.

I have done the rebuild so many times but still same errors ? No funny variables were setup etc.. Btw the gcc was built fine before this nonsense

@NewStudent The fact remains: libAppProtection.so does not belong, but is somehow injected into your build. You'll need to figure out where it comes from and how to get rid of it.
